# How many Pokémon has Misty caught?

Tags: pokemon

What Pokémon did she catch and how many? I tried to search but I couldn’t find it. I found this website while looking for what Pokémon Ash has found, and since I found it I thought that I could find Misty’s Pokémon  as well.

Comment: https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Misty_(anime) hear you can find her pokemon at the end.

Answer (score 1):

**Current Pokemon on her team:**

Goldeen (Belongs to Cerulean Gym.)

Staryu (Belongs to Cerulean Gym.)

Starmie (Belongs to Cerulean Gym.)

Horsea (Caught in Kanto.)

Psyduck (Accidentally caught in Kanto.)

Politoed (Evolved from Poliwhirl, which evolved from Poliwag, caught in the Orange Islands.)

Corsola (Caught in Johto.)

Gyarados (Obtained in Cerulean Gym.)

Dewgong (Evolved from Seel, belongs to Cerulean Gym.)

Luvdisc (Obtained in Cerulean.)

Azurill (Hatched from Egg given from Tracey.)

**Released Pokemon:**

Togetic (Evolved from Togepi, hatched from Egg found in Kanto.)

Source: [MAL](https://myanimelist.net/character/2909/Kasumi)

Answer (score -2):

I found [this article](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Misty_(anime)#Pok.C3.A9mon) listing Misty's Pokémon:

[image: mistys pokemons]
[image: more pokemons]